# What is the code overhead of an Angular component

Tags: angular, angular5

In the Angular 5 code I am building I have a choice of design approaches:

1. Many different small components each doing a specific piece of data
2. A single component which takes an input, and shows the right data by switching on the input

Approach 2 has the advantage that tree shaking will include only the components we want, whereas with approach 1 all the code must be loaded if the component is loaded. But I am concerned about how much extra code I am generating (and my users have to load) because of the numbers of components.

So my question is:

**How much code/data is added to what my app loads because of loading a minimal Angular 5 component?**

Comment: Essentially whatever is not lazy loaded and not removed by Tree Shaking will be loaded as a part of your App. If you're concerned about that, you might want to consider breaking your Application down into `core`, `shared`, and `feature` modules and then [Lazy Loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) feature modules if you can. Also, it's not really recommended to create a single large component as it would be really difficult to manage and unit test and it would be tightly coupled which is not really how it should be.

Comment: I understand the issues, but I need a figure for the overhead in order to work out the tradeoffs. Lazy loading doesn't help me in this case.

Comment: I'm not really sure if taking the first approach would give a significant performance either. Why does Lazy Loading not help in your case? Is this a small sized app and doesn't have that many modules?

Comment: This is a suite of enterprise applications. The components are mostly required up front. And our tests have shown that approach 1 does provide a significant speedup.

Comment: Close voter care to explain?

Comment: If you have made a test showing a noticeable speedup, why haven't you profiled memory/network to have your question answered directly on your specific case?

Comment: Checkout the answer @DJClayworth

Answer (score 2):

### Both approaches are technically the same for Angular.

When Angular compiles, it generates a **single** JS named `main.js`, all the code of all your small components will be there in the same JS, **so there's no less/extra overhead**.

Angular can `lazy-load` your small components, however that's only recommended for an entire functionality when your users will never see something unless a flag is turned on/off.

When `lazy-load` is implemented Angular will generate a second/third/etc JS file just for that extra code (*Ex.* `main-2.js`, `main-3.js`, *the name of the extra files is defined by your lazy-load settings*), you can more about this subject [here](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).

### The difference of both approaches

Seriously, regarding to JS sizes; there's no performance difference on both approaches, Angular handles both with no extra effort. You can validate that I'm telling the truth by reading the generated code inside `main.js`, you'll see that components are just encapsulated variables (for an easy read, try `--build-optimizer=false` and `--source-map=false`). So i recommend you the first approach. Also i strongly recommend you to [Upgrade Angular to version 9 or Latest](https://update.angular.io/#5.0:9.0) *-is not as hard as you may think-* [Ivy](https://angular.io/guide/ivy) and [AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) handles JS generation even better.

Regarding to variable/memory usage at client side, there is an obvious difference because you'll have your small components using individual variables por each one of them. However, as long as your stored data stays the same for both approaches; the maximum memory usage will be the same.

Comment: The components can be encapsulated variables, but that could mean that the objects assigned to each variable could be very large. As well as the quantity of code loaded these is the additional memory from having multiple objects.

Comment: That's correct, my point is that for both approaches you'll have to store your objects somewhere... the memory load is the same. Angular is way better than most developers handling variables usage. It's easier to if you do the test directly by creating two test angular applications. The first using a single big component and the second using the same code, but partitioned into many components.

Comment: Angular has an incredibly great garbage collector for handling objects in memory, he'll take care of removing them when they are not in use, I think is better that angular do this instead of yourself. You just have to always remember the rule *remove ratter than hide*:  https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#why-remove-rather-than-hide

Comment: I checked main.js and indeed there isn't any code related to my components that wasn't actually in the typescript definition, so thanks, yes, it appears there isn't any code that isn't necessary to the component. The stuff about the JS garbage collector isn't really relevant, ( know I have to store objects somewhere and I'm not suggesting trying to take control of JS memory management) but since nobody seems to know what the memory overhead is like I'll take once answer out of two.

Comment: Are you using AOT?? using it or not changes the output at `main.js`, anyways your component code inside it should look something similar to this: `var _path_your_component_name_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__("./src/app/path/your.component.name/your.component.name.ts");`

Comment: Yes to aot, and I think that code doesn't occur in production builds.

Comment: I remember watching a youtube video of a lecture in one ng-conf (cannot tell which one of them nor in which video I saw it) where the person on the stage mentioned that, as strange as it could be, he had noticed a small performance improvement by splitting the components in one of his projects in several smaller components.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of answer by @Pushprajsinh, we should extra take care when we are dealing with data in component, we should keep all get data logic, mapping between data outside of the component.

1. We should use route resolve to fetch and map data, it should reside in separate service.
2. We should move all reusable logic , which is not specific to component, move to a service.

Above two points will take care most of the cases.

Comment: Again, this doesn't actually answer the question.